# Does my program have a runtime error or does my computer not have the power to run my program?

Tags: java

So I started the Euler Project and the first problem was very easy, however I cannot get the answer because the program I created is not running. It compiles fine but when I run it, it never runs. Project Euler says that the problems " with efficient implementation will allow a solution to be obtained on a modestly powered computer in less than one minute." Which leads to my question. Am i stuck in an infinite loop or does my computer not have the power to run my program?

The problem is: If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
public class Euler1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double x = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while( x < 1000)
    {
        if((x/3 == (int)x) || (x/5 == (int)x))
        {
        count++;
        x++;
        total += x;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(total);
}
```

}

Comment: How is x/3 or x/5 ever going to equal x unless x is zero? Your code doesn't make any sense. NB there are no compile errors or runtime errors here, so the tags were irrelevant.

Comment: Protip: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program  is wrong.

```
while( x < 1000)
{
    if((x/3 == (int)x) || (x/5 == (int)x))
    {
        count++;
        x++;
        total += x;
    }
}
```

Notice that x is only incremented if the condition is true. x starts at 1, so the condition is not true, so x never gets incremented and stays at 1.

Also, `x/3 == (int)x` and `x/5 == (int)x` are not correct tests for divisibility. Neither of them are ever true unless x is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if your `if` condition is false in the `while` loop, `x` never gets incremented...

(and it will always be false unless `x` is 0)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting stuck in an infinite loop. Your if-statement is never being called because it will never return true unless `x` is `0`, and thus your `x` variable is never being incremented. I would suggest looking into the `%` (modulus) operator for this problem.